# Problems with <a> in hidden <div>

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Why in desktop mode `<a>` in hidden `<div>` pushing down menu below? It's happening only in Firefox.

Code example is:

HTML:

```
<div id="show-menu"><a href="#">NAVIGATION<a></div>
    <div class="headmenu">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#show-menu {
    display:none;
    clear:both; 
}

.headmenu {
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    height:85px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    color:#232324; 
    text-decoration:none;
    background-image:url("images/menu_bg.jpg"); 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a live link? My guess would be either something is overriding display:none ( check in dev console ) or your html breaks for some reason and a falls outside the div ( again, you can verify in console ).

Comment: Yes, you right. Thanks for tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<a>` tag is not properly closed. You're opening a new tag instead:

```
<div id="show-menu"><a href="#">NAVIGATION<a> <--- here :) </div>
```